# The analytic extension of $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ and an induction

Tags: summation, induction, analytic-continuation

The analytic extension of the sum of the first $n$ reciprocals is given as

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\int_0^1\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}dx$$

I am wondering if $\frac1{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1k$.

My attempt at checking

$$\sum_{k=1}^{1/2}\frac1k=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{x-1}dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{x}+1}dx$$

$$\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{x}+1}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-\sqrt{x})^idx\tag{Binomial Expansion}$$

$$=1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty(-1)^{i+1}\frac{2}{i}$$

$$=1+2\eta(1)$$

Where $\eta(n)$ is the Dirichlet eta function.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{1/2}\frac1k=1+2\eta(1)=1+2\ln(2)$$

I was wondering if I made any mistakes along the way and if it is ok for me to say that is the result.

Second problem:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{3/2}\frac1k=\int_0^1\frac{x^{3/2}-1}{x-1}dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)(x+\sqrt{x}+1)}{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{x+\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+1}dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\sqrt{x}+\frac1{\sqrt{x}+1}dx$$

$$=\frac23+(1+2\ln(2))$$

I pulled that result from the previous problem.

Since this agrees with $\frac1{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1k$, is it possible to prove that this will hold true for any $n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just try to calculate it directly: For $\alpha\geq 1$, we need to try the definition (analytical extension) of $\sum_{k=1}^\alpha\frac{1}{k}$ "appear" in the definition of $\sum_{k=1}^{\alpha+1}\frac{1}{k}$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\alpha+1}\frac{1}{k}&=\int_0^1\frac{x^{\alpha+1}-1}{x-1}dx=\int_0^1\frac{x^{\alpha+1}-x^\alpha+x^\alpha-1}{x-1}dx\\
&=\int_0^1x^\alpha+\int_0^1\frac{x^\alpha-1}{x-1}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha+1}+\sum_{k=1}^\alpha\frac{1}{k}
\end{align*}

Note that these are almost the same calculations as you did in the second problem.

Comment: Ah, that did make sense.  I should've seen it.

Comment: Luiz you know that this is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog

Comment: @user1952009 No, I had never heard of $q$-analogs. I don't see a direct relation with the result in question, also (apart from a formula $(x^\alpha-1)/(x-1)$ being used in both definitions). Care to comment on it?